# Run ElasticSearch Curator with ApiKey auth - is it possible?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-curator

I'm looking at config options for [ElasticSearch Curator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/configfile.html) and I see that there is a way to do auth using Basic auth (username and password).

However I can't find if there is a way to use [ApiKey auth](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-create-api-key.html), is there a way to use it?

ElasticSearch version: 7.17.0
Curator version: 5.8.4

Comment: Which version of curator are you using?

Comment: @Val added to the question, please take a look

Comment: Can you try to use the [`apikey_auth` configuration setting](https://github.com/elastic/curator/blob/7f9461b6692e66341860600470a0ad21fcdbcb71/docs/asciidoc/configuration.asciidoc)?